# Remove white space between html tags php

Tags: php, html, regex, pandoc

I have a problem at converting markdown source into other formats using Pandoc. The whole problem occurs when in markdown is located html; when there are some spaces between 2 html tags, it isn't converted correctly. So what I need is to check the whole markdown source and remove all whitespaces between 2 **different** html tags, e.g.

here is some text in markdown (lorem ipsum)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> here is some text</td>
    <td>some other text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using Pandoc in php, so I think that when the source of markdown is read in a variable, that could be matched and replaced with some `regex`; the output after the replacement should look like:

here is some text in markdown (lorem ipsum)

```
<table><tr><td> here is some text</td><td>some other text</td></tr></table>
```

So just when between `>` and `<` there is nothing else than whitespace, the whitespace should be removed.

Comment: Processing general HTML with regular expressions is doomed to failure (HTML is not a regular – ion the formal sense – language). The personal effects also also [negative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasons you want that? There is probably a good reason for markdown not to remove the spaces and maybe your concerns could be addressed in another way? It just sounds to me that you are doing a hack to avoid something which might be solved in a way better manner.

Comment: I need to convert some template from markdown to .rtf, as I didnt found any library to php which could do that, there is a solution to switch markdown into html and than convert to rtf, pdf,.. and problem is that markdown have inside html source which i need to have after conversion as html,

Comment: Pandoc can convert markdown directly to RTF btw.. Also, you should use markdown tables, not inline HTML tables when you do tables in markdown... http://pandoc.org/README.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property `white-space:pre-wrap;` .
Whitespace will be preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

Comment: `I have a problem at converting markdown source into other formats using Pandoc` - How do you expect css to fix an (apparent) problem with pandoc parsing html with whitespace in it?